# $_POST values are not changing from initial state despite user input

Tags: php, html, forms

I have this code here, within a form:

```
<form method="post" action="">
   <div id="icon-themes" class="icon32"><br></div>
   <h2 class="nav-tab-wrapper"><a class='nav-tab' href='?page=symbiostock-ecommerce-manager&tab=homepage'>Home Settings</a><a class='nav-tab nav-tab-active' href='?page=symbiostock-ecommerce-manager&tab=invoices'>Invoices</a><a class='nav-tab' href='?page=symbiostock-ecommerce-manager&tab=VAT'>VAT Settings</a><a class='nav-tab' href='?page=symbiostock-ecommerce-manager&tab=feed'>Google Product Feed</a></h2>

   <br />
   <label for="ssem_year_num">Year
   <input name="ssem_year_num" value="2014" type="text" />
   </label>
   <label for="ssem_month_num">
      Month
      <select name="ssem_month_num">
         <option  value="1">January</option>
         <option  value="2">February</option>
         <option  value="3">March</option>
         <option  value="4">April</option>
         <option  value="5">May</option>
         <option  value="6">June</option>
         <option  value="7">July</option>
         <option selected value="8">August</option>
         <option  value="9">September</option>
         <option  value="10">October</option>
         <option  value="11">November</option>
         <option  value="12">December</option>
      </select>
   </label>

   <p class="submit"><input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="button button-primary" value="Save Changes"  /></p>
</form>
```

Despite changing the values in the text and select area, they do not seem to change upon form submission, as the `var_dump($_POST)` result shows this:

```
array (size=3)
  'ssem_year_num' => string '2014' (length=4)
  'ssem_month_num' => string '8' (length=1)
  'submit' => string 'Save Changes' (length=12)
```

Having run my HTML through the w3 validator, it appears the HTML is not broken, so I'm left wondering - why aren't the values reflecting user input upon submission?

Comment: You need to post everything from the open to closing `form` tags.

Comment: Does your code include a form with a method of type post?

Comment: TY I'll update this to show form tags

Comment: you should post it to somewhere right? why is your `action=""` empty? where exactly are you getting `var_dump($_POST) ` from? since you have tagged php, shouldn't it point to a some php file?

Comment: I thought when action="" is empty, default is to post to the page it is on...hence I am able to get the values of $_POST --- of course I could ignorant of something here. I've never seen the problem.

Comment: The empty action attribute will do just as you think it will, 1Up, it is not a problem here. Watching the network tab and [submitting your form](http://jsfiddle.net/xs0hjn7a/) with updated values, I see the values change. It must be something else. Check and omit any Javascript that may be running, and confirm that the values *as first seen* by your server have the said values. There is no demonstratable reason why you are having an issue like this in what you've shown. Also, embedding a form within a form can cause issues, so check that you are not doing that as well.

Comment: Thank you - this is on Wordpress, so I suppose things could be getting hyjacked somewhere else - which greatly magnifies the question/problem beyond what I've posted here. I'll run along then and see what else I can do.

Answer (score 2):

for the input text try this:

```
<label for="ssem_year_num">Year
    <input type="text" placeholder="2014" name="ssem_year_num" />
</label>
```

and in the select remove the 'selected' property:

```
....
<option value="8">August</option>
....
```

and see what happens.

Comment: Thank you for that. I put in the placeholder, and it displays properly, but now `$_POST['ssem_year_num']` simply shows empty value.

Comment: Removing 'select' (my mistake) causes the default to be 1, and that does not change when the select changes.

Comment: Removing the values populating the form seen at page load will do nothing to "correct" whatever the OP is seeing here.

Comment: Seems to me that's being manipulated client-side by some javascript. Try renamming both:

    name="ssem_year_num"   to   name="ssem_year_num1"

and

   <select name="ssem_month_num">  to   <select name="ssem_month_num1">

Answer (score 0):

i think your problem is this: *php is a preprocessed language.*

If you are grabbing `var_dump($_POST)` at the same page, nothing should be in `$_POST` since when you load the php, you have not posted your form yet. therefore it will be empty.

put your php into seperate file and call it via `action="submit.php"`, then use `var_dump($_POST)` and see it works!

Comment: The OP has obviously demonstrated the `$_POST` is populated with values, meaning the form was submitted.

Answer (score 0):

Try to rename:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit">
```

To

```
<input type="submit" name="s1" id="s1">
```

And see if that resolves the issue.
I am assuming there is javascript on the page listening for a form.submit event.